# Configure the new XAMPP FTP location

Tags: configuration, ftp, xampp

I got a new computer and installed the latest XAMPP Version (3.2.1), which was quiet a change (they removed password controll). But the changes were not consistent because I can't start the FTP-Server from the control panel even though it is there, because the path to it is incorrect in some config file (not capitalized and with no space). It looks under 
"C:\xampp\filezillaftp\filezillaserver.exe", but acctually it is here 
"C:\xampp\FileZillaFTP\FileZilla server.exe" How can I correct this?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tipp. but I resolved the issue. how would I move the question or did you just mean posting it over there?

Comment: Delete here, re-post there. If you know the solution already, please post it as a answer to your question.

Comment: I just played up my old backup and downgraded it this way.